# Filtered object array length in React Native

Tags: react-native, object, filter, map-function

I have an object array as shown below:

```
data = [
{
"shelf_name" : "Shelf A",
"shelf_size" : "9",
"shelf_color" : "red",
"shelf_height": "100",
"shelf_width" : "150",
},
{
"shelf_name" : "Shelf A",
"shelf_size" : "4",
"shelf_color" : "blue",
"shelf_height": "150",
"shelf_width" : "170",
},
{
"shelf_name" : "Shelf B",
"shelf_size" : "6",
"shelf_color" : "yellow",
"shelf_height": "175",
"shelf_width" : "200",
}
]
```

I am using the filter function to filter the data by shelf_name and then display the data on the screen. My return function looks like this:

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container1}>
          <View style={{height: 250}}>
            <ScrollView
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              style={styles.scrollViewStyle}>
              {data
                .filter(function (shelfName) {
                  return shelfName.shelf_name === 'Shelf A';
                })
                .map((item, index) => {
                  <View key={index} style={styles.productView}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        marginLeft: 5,
                      }}>
                      {item.product_name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>Shelf Size: {item.shelf_size}</Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Height: {item.shelf_height}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Width: {item.shelf_width}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Color: {item.shelf_color}
                    </Text>
                  </View>;
                })}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
         </View>
        </View>
```

*Current Output:*
If the data exists after the filter function it is displayed properly. If the data does not exists nothing is displayed on the screen

*What I am trying to achieve:*
Show the data if the data exists or else show a message that "The data does not exist". To achieve this I tried to check the length of the object after the filter function by using `Object.keys(data).length` inside an if condition. But, I am unable to do so. Please let me know  how do I achieve this.

Comment: Can you use Flatlist ? Flatlist gives you a functionality to display some component when `data` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to achieve: Show the data if the data exists or else show a message that "The data does not exist". To achieve this I tried to check the length of the object after the filter function by using Object.keys(data).length inside an if condition. But, I am unable to do so. Please let me know how do I achieve this.

Have you tried using `data.length`? By what it look like your `data` is always an array, so you don't need the `Object.keys`. In fact using it will always be `true` because beside the `length` key an array object have many other functions.

Try something like...

```
const filteredData = data.filter(function (shelfName) {
    return shelfName.shelf_name === 'Shelf A';
});

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.blue} />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container1}>
          <View style={{height: 250}}>
            <ScrollView
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              style={styles.scrollViewStyle}>
              {!filteredData.length && <Text>The data does not exist</Text>}

              {filteredData
                .map((item, index) => {
                  <View key={index} style={styles.productView}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        marginLeft: 5,
                      }}>
                      {item.product_name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>Shelf Size: {item.shelf_size}</Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Height: {item.shelf_height}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Width: {item.shelf_width}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                      Shelf Color: {item.shelf_color}
                    </Text>
                  </View>;
                })}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
         </View>
        </View>
```

Comment: I want to check the length of the array after the filter function. Can you please tell me how to do that. Your example checks the length before the filter function is applied.

Comment: I've edited the answer. But it's simple, just set a variable like `filteredData` with the result of the `.filter` operation and use it.